# Housing Society management system database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing billing structure for housing society yesterday I googled and gone through banking billing structure and designed my database structure but I am not sure whether this would be correct. So I am putting my billing database structure.

Please tell me if I am wrong any where or any changes has to be done in my database structure.

And one more questions where I have to post society balance (debit, credit )like eg expense Bldg insurance and income like Adv board hoarding and also not sure about balance audit trail (having it in transaction table of separate table with transaction id as FK).

Please note all table will have by default have created,modified time, by and ip address

**Table billingstatement**

```
id   | description                        |  amount  | Bill Month  | userId   | societyId 
 1   | Maint Chrg 1000 sqft x 5 per sqft  |  5000    | Aug-16      | 1001     |  101      
 2   | Water Charges                      |   200    | Aug-16      | 1001     |  101       
 3   | Construction Charges               |   300    | Aug-16      | 1001     |  101
 4   | Reserved Parking chrgs             |   500    | Aug-16      | 1001     |  101
```

**Table Accounts**

```
id   | balance(current bal) |  societyId  | modifiedTime         |
 1   | -6000                |   101       | 2016-01-01 21:01:01  |
 2   | -5000                |   101       | 2016-01-01 21:01:01  |
 3   | 1000                 |   101       | 2016-01-01 21:01:01  |
```

**Table transaction**

```
id  |  amount |  balance | trans_type | trans_time          | account_id | 
 1  |  6000   |   0      |    1       | 2016-01-01 21:01:01 | 1          | 
 2  |  5500   | -6000    |    1       | 2016-02-01 21:01:01 | 2          | 

tran_type :- 1 = Payment by user, 2 = Income to society, 3 = Expense to society
```

**Table map_account_user**

```
map_id | account_id | user_id
 1     |  2         | 1001
```

If account mapping is not present then it means it is a society account and not a user account.

Reference :-

[billing banking desing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/writing-a-simple-bank-schema-how-should-i-keep-my-balances-in-sync-with-their-t)

[banking project sample](http://freeprojectscode.com/java-projects/online-banking-system-academic-project-java/138/)

Comment: No table called "Properties" ? I imagine they will want analysis of data per building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are designing a relational database.  In a relational database, you [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data.

I'm having trouble following your database design because you have too many different fields called id.  Each id field should get a unique name, so people can tell what the different id fields represent.

Let's start with the Transaction table.  Generally table names are singular.  I capitalize table names and column names.  You don't have to follow that convention.

```
Transaction
-----------
Transaction ID
Transaction Type
User ID
Society Account
Transaction Amount
Transaction Time Stamp
...
```

Transaction ID is an auto-incrementing integer.  It is also the primary (clustering) key to the Transaction table.  Transaction Type is 1 = Payment by user, 2 = Income to society, 3 = Expense to society.  I'm not sure what the difference is between Transaction Type 1 and Transaction Type 2.

Either the User ID or the Society Account column is filled in.  The User ID column is filled in for Transaction Type 1 and the Society Account column is filled in for Transaction Types 2 and 3.  The not filled in column is set to null.

Transaction Amount is always a positive value.  Your code will subtract the Transaction Amount from the Society Account for Transaction Type 3.

You will create a unique index for (User ID, Transaction Time Stamp descending, Transaction ID) and a unique index for (Society Account, Transaction Time Stamp descending, Transaction ID).  This allows you to quickly get all the transactions for a user or society account, for a given month.

Next, let's look at the UserAccountBalance table.

```
UserAccountBalance
------------------
User ID
Balance Year and Month
Balance Amount
...
```

The primary key to this table is (User ID, Balance Year and Month descending).  You maintain the historical balances for each month for each User ID.  This allows an auditor to verify the balances by running queries against the Transaction table.

Next, let's look at the SocietyAccountBalance table.

```
SocietyAccountBalance
---------------------
Society Account
Balance Year and Month
Balance Amount
...
```

This table is similar to the UserAccountBalance table, but for Society accounts.

Next, let's look at the Billing table

```
Billing
-------
User ID
Billing Year and Month
Billing Type
Square Feet
Charge per Square Foot
Total Charge
...
```

The primary key is (User ID, Billing Year and Month descending, Billing Type).  I'm assuming that you only get one billing charge per billing type per month.

Billing Type is 1 = Maintenance Charge, 2 = Water Charge, 3 = Construction Charge, 4 = Reserved Parking Charge.  You can generate the text on the bill from the values in this table, so there's no need to store the text in the database.  The Square Feet and Charge per Square Foot columns are filled in for Billing Type 1, otherwise they are null.

You still have to match up the payments with the billings, but this should be enough to get you started on the right path.

Comment: I have one question regarding account balance audit trail .I have not understood about audit trail,  correct me if I am wrong. You mean to stay for every 1st day of the month I will create new row for each user and society account table with opening balance

Comment: @pise:  Yes.  On the first day of every month, you will create a new balance amount row for the users and the Society accounts.

Comment: but then if no transaction is made for that month for a particular user then how the new row opening balance will get create or else do I need to run a batch process for that?

Comment: @pise: Yes, you will have to run a batch process to create all of the balance rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hesitation with storing an aggregate with the entity. Unless the aggregate is very difficult to calculate, you should always account for these by examining the details.

Answer (score 0):

> Really appreciated for your efforts. You reference on banking system is really a best approach. I would like to provide you some ideas which may help you if you feel it is better for you.

Let's start. If you use your description column's data:

{Water Charges
Construction Charges
Reserved Parking chrgs}

as a new columns, your no of rows will be decreased and since you can have efficient data maintenance. For each userId you can have a single row of data rather than maintaining four rows. Just verify below provided example.

For each sq ft you can have a description column separately.

```
id | userId | societyId | BillMonth | MaintChrg | WaterCharges | ConstructionCharges | ReservedParkingCharges | Description
1  | 1001   | 101       | Aug-16    | 5000      | 200          | 300                  | 500                   |  Maint Chrg 1000 sqft x 5 per sqft
2  | 1002   | 101       | Aug-16    | 4000      | 200          | 300                  | 500                   |  Maint Chrg 900 sqft x 5 per sqft
3  | 1003   | 102       | Aug-16    | 5000      | 200          | 300                  | 500                   |  Maint Chrg 900 sqft x 5 per sqft
```

For you doubt on debit and credit use:

debit as expenseBldginsurance
credit as Adv board hoarding

You can also add may other columns like user name, No of peoples, electricity charges, etc.

Comment: I don't understand how pushing charges out column wise would be a good idea. What do you do when new charges are added? How do you lookup all charges that are greater or equal to some value regardless of type?

Comment: Hi Ross, see if charges are within the same column as a data, for each user id multiple rows will be created which causes to occupy large memory space and maintaining multiple rows for the same user is not a right way in database strategy

Comment: @jimmacaulays as ross said what if I have to add new charges I have to add column and I don't think it could be good idea to add new column for every new charges. Anyway thank you for sharing idea's

Comment: Maintaining multiple charges as a data and maintaining same user in multiple column is irrelevant. So have a template of all the charges you require and create a table with them. So that it will be a single row of data for a single user rather than handling in different row

Comment: @Jim Macaulay:  Relational databases are designed to handle rows more efficiently that columns.

Answer (score 0):

The structure works.  I would change the id naming a bit.

account_id  is referenced in some places 
but in the account table it is Id.

I would make it account_id in the Account table.  This makes it easier to locate where you can join for the users of the database.  Every place you call it "Account_Id" is should be the same Account_Id with a single master table that generates it.